# Loading RWeka package crashes R 3.5 session (Windows 10)

Tags: r, crash, rweka

I never had any issues with RWeka package but since yesterday when I updated all my packages, loading RWeka crashes my R session immediately. I reinstalled R (to the newest version of 3.5), rJava and RWeka packages. Didn't have any issues during installations.

I tried loading all dependent libraries separately. All dependent packages (e.g. rJava), except RWekajars. loading RWekajars crashes R session. so I believe that's the culprit. I have reinstalled that package without any errors and still have the same issue. Ruthless crash with no error messages. What other measures should I take?

(Windows 10)

Comment: are you able to replicate the crash with `rJava:::.jpackage("RWekajars", lib.loc=.libPaths())` ?

Comment: yes! that crashes the R session the same way.

Comment: I realised that even .jinit() fails. So i reinstalled Java and it works now. It still doesn't make sense because i had the latest version of Java to begin with. The wonderful stable world of Java.